# What are the methods to reject ocular artifacts in the EEG?

Tags: eeg, signal-processing

Is there any way to remove ocular artifacts from an EEG signal, other than applying independent [component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis), or manual rejection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a review by [Croft & Barry (2000)](http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/biomed/private/papers/croft_barry00.pdf), a number of possible methods exist to prevent, or reject ocular artifacts in the EEG;

**Prevention/reduction of artifact instances**

- Recording with eyes closed -
  A very effective method, but eye closure alters the EEG, *e.g.*, it increases [alpha band activity](http://neurosky.com/2015/05/greek-alphabet-soup-making-sense-of-eeg-bands/);
- Let subjects fixate on a target -
  Method reduces blinks, but does not eliminate them.

**Rejection**

- Exclude trials with amplitudes larger than, *e.g.*, 50 microV  -
  Method works only with a trial-based approach; artifacts below criterion level will remain.

**Reduction**

- Subtract a certain standard voltage when an artifact occurs  -
  A crude method;
- Online attenuation of the EEG signal when an artifact is detected  -
  Works better as the former technique, but is still crude;
- Regression techniques where different electrodes are used to estimate the artifact component in other electrodes  -
  A more sophisticated method with apparently good results.

For details I refer to [Croft & Barry (2000)](http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/biomed/private/papers/croft_barry00.pdf) and the primary literature cited therein.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Croft & Barry *Neurophysiol Clin* (2000); **30**: 5-19](http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/biomed/private/papers/croft_barry00.pdf)</sub>